# How does Angular know where directives are placed in a page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does Angular know where the directives are placed in a page and how does it bind to/monitor those elements?

I was looking through a DOM reference, but getElementbySomething and querySelectorAll don't seem like they'd find an Angular directive.

The articles only mention the listeners passed as arguments to $scope.$watch, so how do the directives know when to call $apply and start the digest cycle?

Comment: Why do you think it would be hard to find the elements? Did you try yourself?

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't try it, but querySelectAll will grab CSS selectors and I don't think a directive can be counted as one according to the W3Schools reference on CSS Selectors. Directives aren't labeled like names, classes, id's or tags so i figured those functions wouldn't be able to identify them while looping through the document.

Comment: @charlietfl even if you could identify the directives in the page with existing DOM functions, how do the directives know when something has changed and to call $apply?

Comment: by creating watchers as the scopes are created

Comment: @charlietfl but the watchers are called in the digest cycle. $apply needs to be called from the directive to start the process. I think they would only call $apply when there is a change. Do the directives have their own event listeners?

Comment: best suggestion is dig through the source code and see how all the pre and post link and compile functions work in the initial directive creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not 'find' directives. When Angular is initialized it processes every single element on the page and determines if it contains a directive that has been registered. This is called the compile phase.

The compile function is called for the directives on the element in priority order and the element that directive belongs to is stored by angular for future use.

Requarding your question about using $apply. That is only needed if something outside the angular lifecycle changes a scope value. Which really only happens if you are binding to a standard event like 'click' within the directive.

Comment: I know the directives call $apply automatically, but the article I was reading didn't mention anything about listeners in the directive. It looks like Angular attaches event handlers to appropriate inputs which trigger the call to $apply -> $digest in the rootScope and all the subsequent watchers in $$watcher. Basically, I wanted to know that Angular automatically adds event handlers where necessary when using certain directives.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find a directive with a querySelector like this:

```
var directive = document.querySelector('[ng-repeat]');
```

You can read any value of a directive like this:

```
console.log(directive.attributes['ng-repeat'].value)
```

Changes in the value are watched or observed within the directive. Why should they change outside of angulars scope? do you want to change them with vanilla javascript?

You could poll the value with an interval. I put together a codepen here: http://codepen.io/rias/pen/bdNgJe?editors=101

```js
var value = 0;

function vanilla_increment_value() {
  value += 1;
  document.getElementById('changeme').attributes['ng-example-directive'].value = value;
}

// fake angular watching for changes outside of the scope
(function() {
  var directive = document.querySelector('[ng-example-directive]');
  var poll = directive.attributes['ng-example-directive'].value;

  // poll change
  setInterval(function() {
    var m = directive.attributes['ng-example-directive'].value;
    if (m != poll) {
      poll = m;
      alert(poll);
    }
  }, 100);
}());
```

```html
<body ng-app>
  <section ng-example-directive="1" id="changeme">
    <button onclick="vanilla_increment_value()">Value +1</button>
  </section>
</body>
```